# How can I write a different value to "Stencil Buffer"?

Tags: user-interface, opengl, stencil-buffer

I'm writing a 2D UI library with OpenGL. Now, I want to make parent view clips it's children by "Stencil Test", I need test it's parent layer value, and write the layer value belong it self for next test.

> For example test 0, and write 1.  test 0, write 2.

Is there any way to do that?  Or I can't use "Stencil Test" to solve my problem? If I can't use this, Any one have a good idea to solve my problem?
    Thanks a lot.

How can I write a different value to "Stencil Buffer"?

Addition:
   Like the picture below, I draw the three rect with three step.  I first draw the red rect with stencil test 0 less or equal to the value in stencil buffer(After now,I will only show the value) and write 0 value.   Second, draw the green rect with stencil test 0 and write 1.  Third, draw blue rect with stencil test 0 and write 2.

[image: pic]

Comment: Do you want to increment the stencil value in a layer is drawn on a pixel? Then look at `glStencilOp` and the `GL_INCR` flag. Otherwise, please clarify for me what you mean by "I need test it's parent layer value, and write the layer value belong it self for next test.".

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I have tried to use GL_INCR and meet a issue.  I have update my question for more detail.

Comment: Well, `GL_INCR` will start to write 1 for your first rect (I guess) and then 2, 3 and so forth. But besides that it should do exactly what you want. So, with `GL_INCR` you should get that the red color rectangle will be 1, green color than 2 and blue color than 3 in the stencil buffer.

Comment: I think by GL_INCR the blue color will be 3 only on green color part. it will be 2 on the red color part. Am I right?  But I need all of the blue shadow part set to 3.

Comment: Hm, could happen, depending how you setup the stencil test. If you let the stencil test pass when >=1, after rendering the red quad, then you would render the whole blue quad on top of the red one. In these cases you might want to run [renderdoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc) to see the stencil result.

Comment: I don't think so. I already let the stencil test pass when >=1.   red part is 1 so it increase to 2, by I want set it to 3.   After more explore on the internet, I found stencil buffer can be change in fragment shader by ARB_shader_stencil_export feature. But AMD and N card's hardware only support

Comment: But AMD and N card's hardware only support 8 bit stencil, so it has less expansibility. So may be I have to find another way, for example: record stencil value in a texture. I don't no...